# What is the canonical approach to passing data to a jQuery UI Dialogue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following markup:

```
<div data-id="1" data-name="Product 1">Product 1 <a href="#" id="delete_1">Delete</a></div><br />
<div data-id="2" data-name="Product 2">Product 2 <a href="#" id="delete_2">Delete</a></div><br />
<div data-id="3" data-name="Product 3">Product 3 <a href="#" id="delete_3">Delete</a></div><br />
<div data-id="4" data-name="Product 4">Product 4 <a href="#" id="delete_4">Delete</a></div><br />

<div id="delete-product" title="Delete product?">
  <p>
    <span 
      class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" 
      style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">
    </span>
    This product will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure? 
  </p> 
</div>
```

I have the following script jQuery UI:

```
$(function () {
  $("#delete-product").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $("a[id^='delete']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
      $("#delete-product").dialog('open');
      return false;
    });

  });
});
```

How do I pass a value to the `Delete` function so I can display it in the dialogue box? I thought about setting a global variable but that's a bit icky.

I don't mind if I just get a reference to the `<a>` tag that raised the click event. From there I can work out the rest.

Comment: @matt - but how do I get at it inside `"Delete": function () {  $(this).dialog("close"); }`   ?

Comment: @elusive - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Kev: This is similar to the global variable approach, but uses a variable that is "globally" available inside of a single function (closure) only. `(function () { var element; $('#delete-dialog').dialog({ /* element is available here */ }); $("a[id^='delete']").each(function () { /* element is available here, too */ }); }()); /* element is _not_ available here */`

Comment: @elusive - why not put that in answer

Comment: @Kev: I like @Mikael Eliasson's approach better ;)

Comment: @elusive - yeah I went with that as works a treat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .data() API in jQuery.

```
$(function () {
  $("#delete-product").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete": function () {
        var id = $(this).data('item-id');
        //Do something with the id
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $("a[id^='delete']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
      var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
      $("#delete-snapshot").data('item-id', id).dialog('open');
      return false;
    });

  });
})
```

EDIT: Just noticed that ID's missmatch for the dialog. But the problem is in the code I copied from your question.

Comment: +1 utilizing .data a great choice here - but I would use .delegate for the anchor clicks rather than an individual click event for each

Comment: sorry when I pasted the code in I wanted to make it a generic example using a names folks will be more familiar with and I missed that id. Your example works a treat. @redsquare - I take your advice on `.delegate()` thanks.

Comment: @redquare Yeah! .data really changed my way to write jQuery. No more ugly hacks or href parsing. What would be the gain of using .delegate? Should be about the same amount of code and as far as I understand perf should not be better. Or am I missing something?

Comment: it cuts some noise out of the code for me and is a nicer way to express my intentions. Couldn't honestly comment on the perf. It's a tree of Virtual Machine snapshots and there's only ever going to be ~10 items on the page.

Comment: @kev 1 event handler is better than n (in your case 10) but imagine a longer list.